# How to manipulate selected option's value to be the same as option text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, html-select

I have this dynamic HTML / JavaScript form that is working great, but I found that when I click submit it is bringing over the value of the option as its index and not as the text within the option.

I have tried altering the JavaScript code but can not seem to figure out how to resolve this.

HTML

```
    <!-- Category -->
    <label for="type">Category<span class="required-input"> *</span></label>
    <select id="type" name="type" onchange="ChangeTypeList()">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="Order Inquiry">Order Inquiry</option>
        <option value="Product Inquiry">Product Inquiry</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Sub Category -->
    <label for="reason">Sub Category</label>
    <select id="reason" name="reason"></select>
```

JavaScript

```
    var reasons = {};
    reasons['Order Inquiry'] = ['Order Status','Order Issue', 'X'];
    reasons['Product Inquiry'] = ['Product Weight', 'Product Quality'];

    function ChangeTypeList() {
        var typeList = document.getElementById("type");
        var reasonsList = document.getElementById("reason");
        var reasonsType = typeList.options[typeList.selectedIndex].value;

        while (reasonsList.options.length) {
            reasonsList.remove(0);
        }
        var decisions = reasons[reasonsType];
        if (decisions) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < decisions.length; i++) {
                var decision = new Option(decisions[i], i);
                reasonsList.options.add(decision);
                // console.log('decision', decision);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I select the first Category option 'Order Inquiry' and console.log:

```
console.log('decision', decision);
```

I see the following in the Console for the Sub Categories:

```
<option value="0">Order Status</option>
<option value="1">Order Issue</option>
<option value="2">X</option>
```

Ideally I want to see this is the Console for the Sub Categories:

```
<option value="Order Status">Order Status</option>
<option value="Order Issue">Order Issue</option>
<option value="X">X</option>
```

Comment: Read [MDN's documentation on the `Option` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option). it takes the text as the first argument and the value as the second.

Comment: Thanks. I will read up on the MDN documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `decisions[i]` as second parameter in `Option`.
 
**Syntax**:`new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected);` More details **[Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)**

```js
var reasons = {};
    reasons['Order Inquiry'] = ['Order Status','Order Issue', 'X'];
    reasons['Product Inquiry'] = ['Product Weight', 'Product Quality'];

    function ChangeTypeList() {
        var typeList = document.getElementById("type");
        var reasonsList = document.getElementById("reason");
        var reasonsType = typeList.options[typeList.selectedIndex].value;

        while (reasonsList.options.length) {
            reasonsList.remove(0);
        }
  var reason = document.getElementById('reason');
        var decisions = reasons[reasonsType];
        if (decisions) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < decisions.length; i++) {
    //This line is changed
                var decision = new Option(decisions[i], decisions[i]);
                reasonsList.options.add(decision);
                console.log('decision', decision);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<label for="type">Category<span class="required-input"> *</span></label>
    <select id="type" name="type" onchange="ChangeTypeList()">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="Order Inquiry">Order Inquiry</option>
        <option value="Product Inquiry">Product Inquiry</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Sub Category -->
    <label for="reason">Sub Category</label>
    <select id="reason" name="reason"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`option` HTML element has a `value` and `text` attribute.

```js
var options = document.getElementById("dropdown").children;

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  options[i].value = options[i].text;
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="0">A</option>
  <option value="1">B</option>
  <option value="2">C</option>
</select>
```